# highlight single contour line

Tags: numpy, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm making a simple contour plot and I want to highlight the zero line by making it thicker and changing the color.

```
cs = ax1.contour(x,y,obscc)
ax1.clabel(cs,inline=1,fontsize=8,fmt='%3.1f')
```

How do I achieve this?
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

HTH -- this is basically the contour example taken from the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.pyplot.contour), just with modified level lines

The object that is returned from the `contour`-method holds a reference to the contour lines in its `collections` attribute.
The contour lines are just common LineCollections.

In the following code snippet the reference to the contour plot is in `CS` (that is `cs` in your question):

```
CS.collections[0].set_linewidth(4)           # the dark blue line
CS.collections[2].set_linewidth(5)           # the cyan line, zero level
CS.collections[2].set_linestyle('dashed')
CS.collections[3].set_linewidth(7)           # the red line
CS.collections[3].set_color('red')
CS.collections[3].set_linestyle('dotted')

type(CS.collections[0])
# matplotlib.collections.LineCollection
```

Here's how to find out about the levels, if you didn't explicitly specify them:

```
CS.levels
array([-1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5])
```

There is also a lot of functionality to format individual labels:

```
CS.labelCValueList    CS.labelIndiceList    CS.labelTextsList
CS.labelCValues       CS.labelLevelList     CS.labelXYs
CS.labelFmt           CS.labelManual        CS.labels
CS.labelFontProps     CS.labelMappable      CS.layers
CS.labelFontSizeList  CS.labelTexts
```

Comment: Thanks :-) This will do nicely.